# LUIS- Doesn't not understand Intent sometime

Tags: azure-language-understanding

We are developing Library BOT using Microsoft BOT.

Here We have created one Intent BookSearch, and Entity BookName, BookAuthor.

We trained LUIS with Simple question,but he works only matching questions.

Ex. I trained LUIS like "I need book", so its works properly
    But with Same question we write "I need **a** book", its doesn't understand to match with book intent.

Can anyone help us here? Like that so many scenario where we found LUIS only works with exact matching questions.

One More Problem, We have Book name, with Three Work, unable to tag three words as a **bookname** entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your model just needs more training with a variety of sentence structures.

LUIS will match the exact intent when it's been trained but needs more examples to get better with novel utterances. So "I need book" vs "I need a book" should be pretty easy for it to learn with more properly labeled utterances.

As for the title with three words, highlighting them all by clicking and dragging across all three is possible.

Answer (score 1):

You have to write more possible questions which user can ask regarding book?

Let me give an example to explain this...

- I need book
- I need a book
- What latest book you have?
- Can you recommend a book to me
- I am looking for book
- I am looking for a book

> In above examples - **Intent** should be -  **FindBook**

- I am looking for C# book?

> In above example - **Intent** should be - **FindBook**, here user has mentioned the *Subject* **(C#)** as well. *Subject* will be *entity*.

- I am looking for C# book written by Joseph Albahari, Ben Albahari

> In above example - Intent Should be one - **FindBook**, here user has mentioned the *Subject* and *Writer*. 
>   *Subject* and *Writer* will be entity.

You have to train your model and feed more possible questions, then only LUIS will work perfectly.

> You can highlight full sentence as well.

[image]